# Rasterio Write Masked Array to TIFF - Shape write and read indices are wrong

Tags: raster, rasterio, masking, array, write

I'm clipping a raster to a shapefile, which returned a masked array, and my goal is to write that masked array to a new .tif file with the correct metadata. I can view the masked array and it looks great. Then, when I write it to a new file using rasterio's write function, something goes wrong, because when I load it back in, it's the wrong shape and it won't plot. See below for details and images:

1. The original raster and polygon shapefile watershed boundary that I want to clip it to.

[image]

2. Clipped output array and image:

```py
out_img, out_transform = mask(rastDat, shapes=coords, crop=True,indexes=1)

out_mask = np.ma.masked_where(out_img<0,out_img)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,12))
outPlot = ax.imshow(out_mask,cmap='terrain')
```

[image]

3. Looks great at this point, and I write it to a new file

```py
#copying metadata from original raster
out_meta = rastDat.meta.copy()

#amending original metadata
out_meta.update({'nodata': -99,
                 'height' : out_img.shape[0],
                 'width' : out_img.shape[1],
                 'transform' : out_transform}) 

#writing and then re-reading the output data to see if it looks good

with rio.open(outLoc,'w',**out_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(out_fill,1)

newClip = rio.open(outLoc)
clipIM = newClip.read(1,masked=True)
```

4. however, the new data is not plotting and has a weird shape. Am I doing something wrong on the writing, or reading, or both? How can I write the raster so that the data will come in and plot like the first figure in this post?

[image]

5. To field any questions, I have tried writing as `dst.write(out_fill)` as well as reading the data in with and without the mask.

Comment: Your code works for me (on my data), though I don't plot it, I just checked `outLoc` displays correctly in QGIS and that `clipIM.shape` was correct. Does `outLoc` display correctly if you open it in QGIS (if you have it installed)?

Comment: Well, I don't have QGIS, but when I load it in an entirely new .py (or ipynb) file, it works! Wow, silly. Thanks so much!!! =D

Answer (score 0):

You may be prescribing the new height and width incorrectly. What happens when you call `out_image.shape` before writing the raster? It may be the shape is actually 1 x 6094 x 4000 (or whatever the width is) and so when you prescribe `shape[0]` as the height you are actually giving it a height of 1. The value of 1 in the zeroth element of the shape tuple is indicating this is a single-band raster (rather than a three-band RGB image, for example).

Try changing the elements of the shape tuple you are assigning to the height and width keys of the metadata:

`# amending original metadata
 out_meta.update({'nodata': -99,
                  'height' : out_img.shape[1],
                  'width' : out_img.shape[2],
                  'transform' : out_transform})`

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for that suggestion. I just looked into it to make sure, but it seems that it's correct when I use shape[0] and shape[1].
if I call:
`out_fill.shape`
I get:
`(6094, 4172)`

out_meta`
And all looks well
`{'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'int16',
 'nodata': -99,
 'width': 4172,
 'height': 6094,
 'count': 1,
 'crs': CRS.from_dict(init='epsg:27200'),
 'transform': Affine(26.683493831244363, 0.0, 2029176.4496368268,
        0.0, -26.683493831244363, 5591892.947473064)}`

Comment: how are you creating `out_fill` ? I don't see it in the code in your example.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. That's just a  temporary copy i made of `out_mask`, which is plotted in (2) of the original post. I had made a copy when I was playing around and called it 'fill'.

Comment: hmm well i am stumped for now - clearly the raster you are writing as the wrong shape (1 x 6094) so something is off. share the data you are working with if possible and maybe myself or someone else can dig deeper

Comment: It's uploaded to a dropbox! see link here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zq9s6fx4ol9quza/AAAqmcs69-BFkMCbJSvrlXn_a?dl=0

Just change the directory on the input files and you're good to go! Thanks in advance for helping me out!!!